# Content of UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, switch-statement

I have a TableView and a Cell that is based on an array. Now I want to change a variable based on witch entry of the array is showed on the cell.

```
var array = ["first", "second", "third"]
var result = String

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

// and here I need the content of the Cell

        switch Cell."content argument" {
            case "first":
                var result = "works"
            case "second":
                var result = "works also"
            case "third":
                var result = "what a surprise, works also"
            default:
                var result = "doesn't work"
        }  

        return Cell

    }
```

and here I need the argument to get the content of the Cell. and please, nothing with "You have to create a new file or function or extension", no, just the arguments please!

Comment: I believe you are looking for

    switch Cell.textLabel?.text

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? What argument and content are you referring to? The object."string" syntax you used is not supported in Swift. Also, I would advise against using capital variable names, but that's another topic.

Comment: thanks, but i tried that before, and that doesn't work, it gives me the error code 'String' cannot be a member in 'String?'

Comment: @PascalCzasny You want to display different UITableViewCell for your array element? Like more than on Custom cell in tableview.

Comment: no i want to change the var result based on witch cell i click

Comment: If what you want to do has something to do with highlighting or selecting cells, please update your question. In that case, you'll need to provide other `UITableViewDelegate` methods. And read the appropriate documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW21

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you post a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you had when you switched based on `Cell.textLabel?.text`, is that textLabel is `Optional`, so it's text is `Optional` too. `Optional` is an enum with two cases, `.Some` and `.None`, that's why your cases didn't work.

There's two possible solutions.

1. Put your switch inside an `if let` statement:

   ```
   Cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

   if let text = Cell.textLabel?.text {
       switch text {
           case "first":
               var result = "works"
           case "second":
               var result = "works also"
           case "third":
               var result = "what a surprise, works also"
           default:
               var result = "doesn't work"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Don't switch based on the cell's content, but rather on your non-Optional data:

   ```
   let text = array[indexPath.row]
   Cell.textLabel?.text = text

   switch text {
       case "first":
           var result = "works"
       case "second":
           var result = "works also"
       case "third":
           var result = "what a surprise, works also"
       default:
           var result = "doesn't work"
   }
   ```

And then there's the problem that you're making a lot of unused local variables, which all happen to be named result. So let's better make it a constant and set it in the switch, and maybe add the result to the cell, like this:

```
    let text = array[indexPath.row]

    let result: String
    switch text {
        case "first":  result = "works"
        case "second": result = "works also"
        case "third":  result = "what a surprise, works also"
        default:       result = "doesn't work"
    }

    Cell.textLabel?.text = text
    Cell.detailTextLabel?.text = result
```

---

## Here's all the code needed:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var array = ["first", "second", "third"]

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let text = array[indexPath.row]
        let result: String
        switch text {
        case "first":  result = "works"
        case "second": result = "works also"
        case "third":  result = "what a surprise, works also"
        default:       result = "doesn't work"
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = result
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried all three methods but it always shows me doesn't work

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, you're probably doing something else wrong, so I added an example with all the code needed. I just tested it and it works perfectly. http://s33.postimg.org/vpqcs323z/Simulator_Screen_Shot_Jun_8_2016_12_32_21_PM.png

Comment: It does work… I even uploaded a screenshot! Don't believe me? here, download the project: http://www.mediafire.com/download/w6ju2v2takp2lfy/test.zip

Comment: okay, now it does work part time, because on every cell i get the result for "third" so on every cell there is what a surprise works also